# Passing variables inside Appdelegate

Tags: objective-c, variables, appdelegate

When I use a variable inside `AppDelegate` and then I use it inside a function the variable doesn't change its value!

Any help? I use objective c

```
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
        // Show alert for push notifications recevied while the
    // app is running

    NSString *message = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]
                         objectForKey:@"alert"];


    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@""
                          message:message
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
```

How can I get message outside of this function?

Comment: Have you considered storing the message inside SharedPreferences in order to retrieve it anywhere without a reference to AppDelegate? It may be a cleaner solution than referencing and casting the AppDelegate.

Comment: declare variable in outside fuction

Comment: Martino Lessio how can i do that?
I want to use it inside appdelegate not to other viewcontrollers

Answer (score 2):

You can make a class variable :

```
NSString *mesage;//You can use this variable anywhere in AppDelegate

 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
        // Show alert for push notifications recevied while the
    // app is running

    message = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]
                         objectForKey:@"alert"];


    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@""
                          message:message
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
```

Comment: The variable message is null until "didReceiveRemoteNotification" is called

Comment: i sent a push and opened log in xcode and i get a null

Comment: Are you sure that "[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]
                         objectForKey:@"alert"];" is not  null?

Comment: here is what i've done:    run app from xcode to my device, opened app, close app then sent a push, in my screen i get the push open the app and in function didbecomeactive  i have put the nslog message and i get the null

Comment: Can the person who voted this answer as helpful help me too plz?

Comment: @user3704857 see my comment above : Are you sure that "[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]
                         objectForKey:@"alert"];" is not  null?

Comment: after some tests i figure out that i can't change any variable in this function in any other function it works